# Capturing the value of pattern in UNIX and writing to another file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a file

```
   #InboxPulse.jmx
    request.threads3=10
    request.loop=10
    duration=300
    request.ramp=6

   #LaunchPulse.jmx
    request.threads1=20
    request.loop1=5
    duration1=300
    request.ramp1=6

   #BankRetail.jmx
    request.threads2=30
     request.loop2=7
     duration2=300
     request.ramp2=6
```

I would like to capture the values for

```
   request.threads2
    request.threads1
    request.threads3
```

into another file like this:

```
  10
  20
  30
```

I tried this

```
awk '/request.threads[0-9]{1,10}=/{print $NF}' build.properties >> sum.txt
```

It gives the output as:

```
  request.threads3=10
  request.threads1=20
  request.threads2=30
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: use `awk -F"=" '/request../{....}' file` Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Extracting values

```
$ grep -oP 'request.threads\d+=\K\d+' build.properties 
10
20
30
```

Add `> sum.txt` to command to save output to a file

2) If sum of those values is needed

```
$ perl -lne '($v)=/request.threads\d+=\K(\d+)/; $s+=$v; END{print $s}' build.properties
60
```

Answer (score 3):

Split on the `=` sign, match on field 1, print field 2:

```
awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /request.threads[0-9]+$/ {print $2}' build.properties >> sum.txt
```

Comment: Awesome this works , Thanks Jonathan.
I am planning to write while loop for this to write on a file

Comment: YW.  I'm not clear why you'd need a while loop; `awk` provides an automatic loop anyway.  However, I don't have enough information to be sure that a while loop somewhere is inappropriate — it is just a little unexpected.

Comment: Also note that the script shown doesn't tolerate spaces before the equals sign, but it is easy to fix if that's what you want.

Comment: I would want to capture these values sum it up and use the total as an input in an other file

Comment: `awk` can do the summing.  It can write the total to another file. `… { print $2; sum += $2; } END { print sum >> "otherfile.txt" }`

Comment: I tried this running once after the other
awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /request.threads[0-9]*$/ {print $2}' build.properties >> sum.txt
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' sum.txt

Comment: That would work, but runs `awk` twice when once is sufficient.  While `awk` is not a slow program, it is still generally better to avoid running it more often than necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, you use back-ticks in comments to get 'code' inserted: ``…`code here`…`` (and demonstrating it is harder).

Comment: @SirajSyed listen to what Jonathan is telling you - you neither need nor want a shell loop (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for just some of the reasons we are telling you that).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Kudos!!

Comment: @SirajSyed  : Don't forget to accept the answer that provides you with the help you need. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242 . Pluse-uno for excellent answer and tech support ;-) . Good luck to all.